# Checkbox to add multiple values mysql

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

i have an html page, where there is a form and saves the results into MySQL. The problem is that the checkbox, saves only one value on the MySQL table. What do i have to do, in order to save multiple values inside the db column?

HTML Code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="rating[]" value="Homepage">Homepage
<input type="checkbox" name="rating[]" value="Facilities">Facilities
<input type="checkbox" name="rating[]" value="reservation">Reservation
<input type="checkbox" name="rating[]" value="Contact">Contact
```

PHP Code:

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="INSERT INTO db (firstname, lastname, password, email, address, postcode,   country, phonenumber, rating, subscribe)
VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$password', '$email', '$address', '$postcode','$country', '$phonenumber', '$rating', '$subscribe')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo " Success!";
```

Comment: Your database does not seem to have room for such information. You are missing a "db to rating" table to be linked from "db".

Comment: can you give structure for rating column in your database thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you have three options.

First.

Create another table and connect them with foreign key.

Second.

Make checkboxes have value and do bit masking.

Ex)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="something[]" value="1">blah
<input type="checkbox" name="something[]" value="2">blah2
<input type="checkbox" name="something[]" value="4">blah3
```

If someone check "blah" and "blah3", make them 5. (1 & 4)

Like this:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($rating); $i++)
{
    $rating_value &= $rating[$i];
}
```

And save it to database in integer.

Third.

Join them into one string and save it to database in string(like VARCHAR).

Comment: If you don't have many "rating" field(under 32 if you are using inter to save this value), you can use second one. But you have to another constant to distinguish each value. So i almost use first one.

Comment: I tried the second solution, but still it saves one value!

Comment: Can i see your source code? It saves only one value and you have to split this value. If you have value 5, it means, 101 in binary. It means third checkbox and first checkbox is checked. Use AND operation to split this value.

Comment: for($i=0; $i<count($rating); $i++)
{
    $rating_value &= $rating[$i];

  
  //proceed to the insert statement
     
  $sql="INSERT INTO customers (firstname, lastname, password, email, address, postcode,   country, phonenumber, rating, subscribe)
VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$password', '$email', '$address', '$postcode','$country', '$phonenumber', '$rating', '$subscribe')";
    }

Comment: It is wrong. You have to save $rating_value NOT $rating, and make sql query after $rating_value is completely calculated. Try this : for($i=0; $i<count($rating); $i++) { $rating_value &= $rating[$i]; //proceed to the insert statement } $sql="INSERT INTO customers (firstname, lastname, password, email, address, postcode, country, phonenumber, rating, subscribe) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$password', '$email', '$address', '$postcode','$country', '$phonenumber', '$rating_value', '$subscribe')";

Comment: I got the following error message: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given. Should i change anything at the HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

If `$rating` is an array try [**implode()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$sql="INSERT INTO db (firstname, lastname, password, email, address, postcode,   country, phonenumber, rating, subscribe)
VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$password', '$email', '$address', '$postcode','$country', '$phonenumber', '".implode(',',$rating)."', '$subscribe')";
```

Comment: Then I can figure out the following questions: how do I search by rating? how do I sort by rating? how do I remove a rating?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario correct. depends on OP how he wants to store.

Answer (score -1):

I strongly recommend you read the following stuff:

- [How to loop an array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)
- [How to use prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

But you don't have a PHP or HTML problem yet. You are trying to store information in a database that doesn't have a place to do so.

You need at least two extra tables:

- A `rating` master table with:

  - `rating_id` (auto-increment or arbitrary code)
  - `rating_value` (e.g. 'Poor', 'Average', 'Good'...)

  ... where you store the available ratings.
- A `db_rating` table with:

  - `db_id` (`db`'s primary key)
  - `rating_id` (`rating`'s primary key)

  ... where you store the relationships.

... and them remove your current `db.rating` column.

Comment: In fact, only one of those is needed, since this is a one-to-many case. The table in OP's question needs to be added an `id` field which can then be linked to all the `rating` rows, which would include said `id` and `rating`.

Comment: @Antti29 He has checkboxes, not radio buttons, and he's explicitly asked to *save multiple values*.

Comment: Yes, which would be stored in the `ratings` table, linked to the original table with `id`. The `ratings` table would have multiple rows for those multiple values. Radio buttons wouldn't require any additional tables at all.

Comment: @Antti29 Since he has checkboxes (rather than allowing free input) I'm also assuming that ratings are normalised and must be chosen from a fixed list. I've added some examples to clarify it.